# More efficient implementation for comparing coefficient lists in a Do-loop

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

I'm wondering how to speed up the following code so it actually computes for $n=2$:

```
f[n_] := Expand[Sum[FunctionExpand[QBinomial[n, j, q]]*q^(j^2), {j, 0, n}]]

lhs[n_] := Sum[(-1)^j*q^(j(5j + 1)/2), {j, -n, n}]

rhs3[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, g_, h_] := 
  Expand[q^a - f[1]*q^b*Product[1 - q^i, {i, c, d}] + f[2]*q^e*Product[1 - q^i, {i, g, h}]]

B[n_] := 
  Do[
    If[CoefficientList[lhs[n], q] == CoefficientList[rhs3[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, g_, h_], q], 
      Print[{a,b,c,d,e,g,h}]], 
    {a, 0, 15}, {b, 0, 15}, {c, 1, 5}, {d, 1, 5}, {e, 0,15}, {g, 1, 5}, {h, 1, 5}]
```

A Do loop with this many iterators may be too much computing, but there must be some built-in constructs which allow for an effective implementation.

Sample input would be `B[2]`.  Sample output would be `{11,1,1,1,1,2,3}` (which is actually one possible solution.  However, the point is to print all possible solutions, so the actual output would be a number of such lists.)

Edit:

I want to emphasize that I would like to see an approach that will work for **more complicated functions for rhs3[a_, ...] that involve a few more iterator variables.**  To be specific, I would like to execute the comparison at least somewhat quickly for the following  RHS with $n=3$ (and I'll label it as rhs3):

```
rhs3[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, g_, h_, j_, k_, l_, x_, r_, y_] := 
  Expand[-f[3*x + y]*q^a + f[3*x + r + y]*q^b*Product[1 - q^i, {i, c, d}] 
    - f[3*x + 2*r + y]*q^e*Product[1 - q^i, {i, g, h}]] 
      + f[3*x + 3*r + y]*q^j*Product[1 - q^i, {i, k, l}]]
```

with the following variable ranges: `{a, 0, 30}, {b, 0, 25}, {c, 1, 7}, {d, c, 7}, {e, 0, 20}, {g, 1, 7}, {h, g, 7}, {j, 0, 15}, {k, 1, 7}, {l, k, 7}, {x, 0, 5}, {r, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}`.  This is of course asking for a lot, but I want to state the nature of the problem in full generality for future visitors.

Comment: You could clarify the question by adding a sample input together with the desired output.

Comment: You don't define `lhs`.

Comment: Sure, but you might attract more takers if the gist of the question (as hinted at in the title) is immediately obvious in a MWE. This would also make it possibly more useful for future visitors.

Comment: @Yves Klett I've clarified a bit.  I can't give a complete example because of the nature of the problem, but hopefully this is enough clarification.

Comment: Should  `q` be defined somewhere?

Comment: @Yves Klett No, these are polynomials in q, hence the CoefficientList call.

Comment: Then your code sure produces some hefty output. After running it for several minutes, my patience gave out.

Comment: @Yves Klett As in you are getting many seven-tuples (a,b,c,d,e,g,h) that satisfy this?  This is not at all expected (and also not what is being outputted for me,) unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: There are `16^3 5^4 == 2560000` iterations.  Calculating and comparing the coefficient lists takes an average of 0.001110 sec. each (the average over the first five seconds worth) on my MacBook Pro.  That gives an estimate of over 2800 seconds of running time to do all the comparisons.  To be faster than that, it seems you would have to speed up the calculation of the coefficient lists, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: @Michael E2 How about implementing the condition $c \le d$ and $g \le h$.  (How to do this in the Do-loop?)  This severely cuts the time.  Also, how about not comparing lists and using a fixed value for q?

Comment: Your `Do` iterators can depend on those to the left, ie. `Do[ ... {g,1,5},{h,g,5} ]` to get only `h>=g `

Comment: This doesn't help, still a massive number of comparisons.  Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: The full generality escapes me.  What would the `rhs3` for a general `n` be?  It's best to state the question you want answered from the beginning.  The original question emphasized you wanted the result for `n = 2`.  Now you've added the specific definition of `rhs3` for `n = 3` but state you want "larger `n`".

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, my mistake for not being clear from the beginning. I've edited the post so that this confusion does not arise for others. rhs3 for general $n$ essentially includes $n+1$ separate factors that are added together. However, it is my belief that finding all 13-tuples which satisfy lhs[3]=rhs3 ($n=3$ case) will provide enough intuition for me while saving unnecessary computation.  (For example the extra computation that would come with $16$ parameters in the $n=4$ case.) Is the current question and background absolutely clear?

Comment: You do realize that your latest variable range constitutes almost two trillion cases, don't you?  On my Macbook Pro, an empty `Do` loop would take nearly 30000 sec.; one that adds four numbers (your `rhs` has four numbers) would take 500000 sec.; compiled it would take 40000 sec.  Then figure in the time it takes to calculate the four numbers to be added.  The problem is easily parallelized, if you have access to many processors.  I'm having doubts about the practicality of addressing this problem....

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea..: work with a specific q:

```
 rhs32[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, g_, h_] := 
        With[{q = 2}, 
            Expand[q^a - f[1]*q^b*Product[1 - q^i, {i, c, d}] + 
             f[2]*q^e*Product[1 - q^i, {i, g, h}]]]

 (list = Flatten[
        Table[{{a, b, c, d, e, g, h}, rhs32[a, b, c, d, e, g, h]}, {a, 0,15},
           {b, 0, 15}, {c, 1, 5}, {d, c, 5}, {e, 0, 15},
           {g, 1, 5}, {h, g, 5}], 6]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 352.067372  ( 6 minutes )

Now find possible matches to `lhs'[n]`

```
  pmatch = Select[list, #[[2]] == (lhs[2] /. q -> 2) & ]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4}, 2549},
>    {{7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 4}, 2549},
>    {{9, 0, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3}, 2549},
>    {{11, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3},2549}}
> ```

now go back and check analytically:

```
 Select[ {#[[1]], CoefficientList[rhs3 @@ #[[1]], q]} & /@ 
       pmatch , #[[2]] === CoefficientList[lhs[2], q] &]
```

> {{{11, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3}, {1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}}}

Comment: no, that's the value of lhs[2] with q=2 .  That `Table` takes a few minutes but not unreasonable (and note you only do it once, not for each n. )

Comment: Ok six minutes is not unreasonable, but it quickly becomes unreasonable once I introduce three more parameters and a function with one more Product (which I don't think is asking too much from Mathematica.)  Any ways to shave off some time here?  This is still much in the same vein as what I proposed in my original post.  Is Mathematica really not designed to handle simple guessing problems like this?

Comment: This needs about 10 seconds:   `AbsoluteTiming[f[n_, q_] := f[n, q] = Expand[Sum[FunctionExpand[QBinomial[n, j, 
          q]]*q^j^2, {j, 0, n}]]; 
   lhs[n_, q_] := lhs[n, q] = Sum[(-1)^j*q^(j*((5*j + 1)/2)), {j, -n, n}]; rhs32[q_, a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, g_, h_] := Expand[q^a - f[1, q]*q^b*Product[1 - q^i, {i, c, d}] + f[2, q]*q^e*Product[1 - q^i, {i, g, h}]]; list = 
 Flatten[ParallelTable[{{a, b, c, d, e, g, h}, rhs32[2, a, b, c, d, e, g, h]}, {a, 0, 15}, {b, 0, 15}, {c, 1, 5}, {d, c, 5}, {e, 0, 15}, {g, 1, 5}, {h, g, 5}], 6]; pmatch = 
    Select[list, #1[[2]] == lhs[2, 2] & ]]`

Comment: It still takes a long time to generate the following table: `rhs23[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, g_, h_, j_, k_, l_] := With[{q = 2}, Expand[-q^a + f[1]*q^b*Product[1 - q^i, {i, c, d}] - f[2]*q^e*Product[1 - q^i, {i, g, h}] + f[3]*q^j*Product[1 - q^i, {i, k, l}]]]; list = Flatten[ParallelTable[{{a, b, c, d, e, g, h, j, k, l}, rhs23[a, b, c, d, e, g, h, j, k, l]}, {a, 0, 25}, {b, 0, 15}, {c, 1, 10}, {d, c, 10}, {e, 0, 15}, {g, 1, 10}, {h, g, 10}, {j, 0, 5}, {k, 1, 10}, {l, k, 10}], 9] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: By how much is Parallel supposed to cut down the time?  Because I ran what was in the previous comment overnight using george2079's approach with no success.

Comment: +1 for showing how to use a number for `q`.

Comment: @george2079 Your pmatch doesn't return what you say it returns. (it returns nothing for me.)

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested and @george2079 showed, using a specific value of `q` can help avoid the slowness of `CoefficientList` by eliminating many cases.  Compiling can speed up the process more -- well, a lot more on a 4(8)-core i7.

Here `params` represents `{a, b, c, d, e, g, h}`.  The values to iterate through are stored in `iter`.  We use Pick to pick out the one(s) for which equality holds.  The coefficients can be checked

```
Clear[bC];

bC = With[{f1 = f[1], f2 = f[2], lhs2 = lhs[2], prod0 = 1 - q^# & /@ Range[5]},
   Compile[{{q, _Integer}, {params, _Integer, 1}},
    Module[{prod = prod0},
     If[params[[3]] > params[[4]] || params[[6]] > params[[7]],
      1,                              (* nonzero for out-of-order parameters *)
      q^params[[1]] -                 (* rhs - lhs *)
       Fold[#1*#2 &, f1*q^params[[2]], 
        prod[[ params[[3]] ;; params[[4]] ]] ] + 
       Fold[#1*#2 &, f2*q^params[[5]], 
        prod[[ params[[6]] ;; params[[7]] ]] ] - lhs2]
     ],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
   ];

(iter = Tuples[{Range[0, 15], Range[0, 15], Range[5], Range[5], 
     Range[0, 15], Range[5], Range[5]}];
 Pick[iter, bC[3, iter], 0]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {1.415915, {{11, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3}}}
*)

CoefficientList[lhs[2], q] == CoefficientList[rhs3 @@ %[[-1, 1]], q]
(*
  True
*)
```

[Note: The general form of `Table` used by @george2079 does not compile, so I used all of the tuples.  Maybe there's another way to generate only the proper ones.]

Comment: Actually, ``Flatten[Table[{a, b, c, d, e, g, h}, {a, 0, 15}, {b, 0, 15}, {c, 1, 5}, {d, c, 5}, {e, 0, 15}, {g, 1, 5}, {h, g, 5}], 6] // Developer`ToPackedArray`` takes less than a second.  It uses ~170 MB of memory that are packed down to 50 MB.  But if the next three parameters each have a range of 1 to 5, then that translates to 20 GB packed down to 6 GB, a lot more if the range is 1 to 15.  You might be able to chunk it.

Comment: Please look at my response to your comment above and edit to the original post.