# Timing Differences

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

In [More efficient implementation for comparing coefficient lists in a Do-loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/more-efficient-implementation-for-comparing-coefficient-lists-in-a-do-loop) link, george2079 posts in his first answer a piece of code that takes 352 seconds to compute.  When I run this same piece of code on my 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro laptop, it takes 853 seconds.  What are the reasons for this, and how can I get the code running optimally on my machine?  (Would it be appreciably faster if I used a desktop?)  Perhaps this question is best posed to George2079, but the original thread is unfortunately dead and there doesn't seem to be a way to contact individual users.

Comment: Is the end goal you want to do this for various `n` and get the loop iterator values where the lhs coeff. list matches the right, or is it just this one-shot (`n`=2) you want to speed up?

Comment: If use for multiple `n` is the goal, just build a table of rhs3 coefficient lists (perhaps with indices added for each entry) *once* - since this doesn't change for differing lhs. This will take time (you're doing *way* more work than needed, there's a pattern to coeff.s you could take advantage of to short-circuit work, don't have time right now to analyze) - but once done, you need only get coeff. list to a given lhs `n`, then *do a lookup* (`Cases`, `Select`, whatever) into the table, will be quite quick.

Comment: @rasher Yes, I would like to do this for various `n` with maybe 10 more iterator variables.  (This problem in question is somewhat of an intermediate step, which is why I'm looking for a better approach.)  The rhs3 coefficient lists change for differing lhs.  If you read the first comment and the ensuing comments I believe that you will see this is what was done, in fact for a particular q so the expansion would be numeric instead of symbolic.  Not sure however if you're proposing something slightly different.

Comment: Then you should update the original question to reflect this - one should not be required to read the comments on a question to determine the examples provided are for one specific case - anyone reading the code as it is would infer the RHS3 does not depend on N in any way... regardless, based on your reply, disregard earlier comment, you need to focus on smarter way to short-circuit the work, probably via number-theoretic characteristics of generated polys...

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my reply to you.  Indeed rhs3 does not depend on n in this example.  If it is indeed the unfortunate situation that Mathematica can't provide an answer to the problem in the current state, can you answer the question I posed originally?  Even the pmatch function in george2079's answer does not return for me what it claims to return, so the problem is not only that it takes more than twice as long for his code to run on my machine.

Comment: I'll happily take a longer look - busy on something else right now, but within next 24Hr I'll reply there with anything I come up with...

Comment: @rasher Great - I've edited the original post there to reflect what I want in full generality.

Comment: If you want to contact individuals you could post a comment below one of their posts, and removing this after you get a response.

Comment: @rasher Were you able to deduce anything about the problem in the edit?

Comment: @Jonny: Working on it - may be a bit, my number theory is very rusty...

Comment: @rasher Hmmm it was my impression the issue was more about writing an efficient program than the underlying math, but perhaps I am wrong.  Sjoerd, do you mean deleting a comment that is a response to another user's answer or comment (or both?)

Comment: @Jonny: "Efficient" brute-force won't matter - in your updated example, you would be searching a space of over ~7.5 *trillion* cases - even if you could do *everything* for one case in a microsecond (not going to happen), you're looking at ~3 months of continuous computing. You need to drastically short-circuit the work using some of the ideas other posters' commented on, or by taking advantage of the characteristics of what's generated by RHS* to skip most cases outright - hence the number theory slant. It might be worthwhile posting on *math* stack - might get some num. th. replies.

Comment: @rasher Ok, I understand.  Is there a way to generate only the "proper" tuples in Michael E2's answer?  Tell me if you don't understand that definition from george2079's answer (d ranges from c to 5, instead of 1 to 5.)  That would at least make 10 parameters, instead of 13, feasible.